# what is "{0}" in C?

Tags: c

What does `char buf[MAXDATASIZE] = { 0 };`'s `{0}` means?

tried to print it out but it print nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        char buf[100] = { 0 };
        printf("%s",buf);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's the **universal zero-initializer** :) It works for (it sets to zero, the right kind of zero) anything *(for initialization)*: `int k = {0}; char *data = {0}; _Complex double x = {0}; struct whatever array[42] = {0}; /* ... */`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is just an initializer list for an array.  So it's very like the normal syntax:

```
char buf[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

However, the C standard states that if you don't provide enough elements in your initializer list, it will default-initialize the rest of them.  So in your code, all elements of `buf` will end up initialized to `0`.

`printf` doesn't display anything because `buf` is effectively a zero-length string.

Comment: So... It is *explicitly stated* that the first char will be `0`, while others will *default* to `0`? Would `char buf[100] = {65, 66, 67};` initialize `buf` to have `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'` as first three elements and all other would *default* to `0`? Would `char buf[100];` be non-initialized, i.e., would it contain unexpected values (whatever was written to the memory before reserving it)?

Comment: @binaryLV: Yes, everything you said is correct.  The only exception is that if you write `char buf[100];` as a global or as a static, it will be initialised to zero (in all other contexts, it will not be initialized).

Comment: I thought only static globals were zero initialized? Would appreciate some clarification on that.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning an array to the buffer.

In the particular case of string, usually, the character whose ASCII value is 0 terminates the string.

For example, if you wanted to put a string that reads 'Hello world' inside the string you could have done

```
char buf[100] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', 0};
```

or

```
char buf[100] = "Hello world";
```

Anyway, your code prints nothing because you are trying to print a string with length zero, that is an empty string.

Comment: `0` and `"\0"` are almost exactly the same thing. The first is converted from `int` to `char`; the second is an array of 2 chars, both having the same zero value. There is no portability issue here.