# Avoiding memset for a multi-type structure

Tags: c, memcpy, memset

I would like to avoid using `memset()` on a structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    float param1;
} StructA;

typedef struct {
    StructA a;
    unsigned int state;
    float param2;
} Object;
```

Can I do something like this (pseudo code, I can't check right now)?

```
Object obj;
int *adr = (int*)&obj;
for (int i; i < sizeof(obj); i++) {
    *adr++ = 0;
}
```

Will it set every member of obj to zero?

**EDIT**: to answer questions on comments.
I have been working on some cases (with uni-type structures), where `memset` is twice as slow than initializing *by hand*. So I will consider trying initializing multi-type structure as well.

Avoiding `memcpy()` would be nice too (avoiding the `<string.h>` lib).

Comment: `int* adr`-> `char* adr`.  Besides this, the answer is yes.

Comment: Why would you like to avoid `memset()`? And if you really want to, don't use `int` use `unsigned char` instead. But you should use `memset()` instead, you really should.

Comment: Actually what he does is the same as `memset`.

Comment: `I would like to avoid using memset` Why? If you're doing this for performance reasons, you're likely to be surprised.  `memset` will likely be faster - without violating aliasing rules.

Comment: `memset` may be slower or not. The only way to find out is to profile it.

Comment: *memset is twice as slow than initializing "by hand"* You have either a broken standard library or a broken way to measure performance.

Comment: `memset` initializes the structure to all bits zero. This would initialize the integers and the floats to 0 on IEEE compliant architectures but the C Standard does not guarantee it.  On an exotic system, this might not initialize `param1` or `param2` to `0.0`. If the hand coded initialization is faster, use that, or use a static initializer: `Object obj = { 0 };`

Answer (score 5):

The *universal zero initializer* initializes everything (recursively) to zero of the proper type.

```
Object object = {0};
```

Comment: Yes, and there are multiple answers about that in SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434865/quickest-way-to-initialize-an-array-of-structures-to-all-0s, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11152160/initializing-a-struct-to-0,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7064314/what-is-0-in-c etc. But this solution allows *initializing* a structure variable during creation only, while `memset()` or a loop in the question allow *re-initializng* an already existing variable.

Comment: I tried it sometime back, it works. But I remember I was getting "missing initializer for member" warning.

Comment: The text of the warning could be a little more helpful, maybe: "missing initializer for member; using 0 for unspecified members, recursively, as the Standard mandates."

Comment: Probably not relevant for this case but this method is dependent on *where* the variable is stored.

Comment: Nice answer, but like it was said, I do not want to set these structures at creation, but later.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "zero" object, then copy it to other objects of the same type. Maybe it's faster than `memset()`, I haven't tested efficiency.

```
const Object zeroobject = {0};

/* ... */
Object obj;
memcpy(&obj, &zeroobject, sizeof obj);
/* assignment may work too */
obj = zeroobject;
```

Comment: `<string.h>` is a header. The functions declared there are part of the C Standard Library. The best way to avoid the C Standard Library is to use a free-standing implementation.

Comment: @Bebs: as pmg points out, `memcpy` is not needed, `obj = zeroobject;` copies the default object onto `obj` as efficiently as possible, taking advantage of the intrinsic alignment of `Object` instances. `memcpy` and `memset` might need extra tests to determine how to perform the copy or the initialization and for small structures such as this, the overhead of a function call might be noticeable if `memset` or `memcpy` are not generated inline. Inspect the code generated by the compiler, run benchmarks, play with compiler options... but remember that micro-optimizing is short term only.

Answer (score 1):

`memset` initializes the structure to all bits zero. This would initialize the integers and the floats to 0 on IEEE compliant architectures but the C Standard does not guarantee it. On an exotic system, this might not initialize `param1` or `param2` to `0.0`.

If the hand coded initialization is faster, use that, or use a static initializer:

```
Object obj = { 0 };
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea, but I don't want to set it to zero at the creation, only later.

Answer (score 0):

No.

I would prefer to use memset:

```
memset(&obj, 0, sizeof(obj));
```

Or if you want it to do your way:

```
char* adr = (char*)&obj;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(obj); i++)
{
    *adr++ = 0;
}
```

Comment: the second method uses an uninitialized `i` and breaks the strict aliasing rule, if you read the char `0`s from the struct via the members.

Comment: @mch: I think `char *` is a special case where the strict aliasing rule does not apply.

Comment: @PaulR if you write something via a `int *`, you are allowed to read it with a `char *`, but not the other way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule says "You can use `char*` for aliasing instead of your system's word. The rules allow an exception for `char*` (including `signed char` and `unsigned char`). It's always assumed that `char*` aliases other types. However this won't work the other way: there's no assumption that your struct aliases a buffer of chars."

Comment: @mch: ah, OK - thanks for the clarification - so how is `memset` initialisation of a struct valid then, since a simple implementation presumably just writes zeroes via a `char *` pointer ?

Comment: @PaulR this is a good question and I cannot find the link to the answer. If I remember correct `memset` is written in assembler to omit the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @mch: interesting - thanks - it certainly seems that you couldn't write a "correct" `memset` implementation in C without violating strict aliasing rules then.

Comment: @mch That is not true. `memset` is specifically  mentioned to work in terms of characters. Writing through `char *` *is* allowed, but it's programmers responsibility to make sure that there are no trap presentations and such.

Comment: @user694733 You are allowed to use `memset` on an object or array, but if you are using a `char *` to set all elements of an object to zero, you break the strict aliasing rule if you read the values of the object members, so http://ideone.com/sAGR2J is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @mch Code you linked is not UB. N1570 6.5p7 specifically mentions that character type is allowed to alias any object. Assignment through `char*` does not change the *effective type* of the original variable. As I said before, it may be possible that some types have trap presentations which might be set and then triggered when reading through original value, but whether that happens or not is *implementation defined* (explained in various paragraphs in 6.2.6.1).

Comment: @user694733 a `char *` can alias any object, but in this case it is the opposite. An `int *` cannot alias a `char *`, so if you write with the `char *` you are not allowed to read the `int`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/3684343

Comment: @mch *An `int *` cannot alias a `char *`* Agreed. But this answer doesn't do so, and neither does the ideone example either. I have read the answer you linked before, but it doesn't do very good job at explaining it, answers below it are better. If you want to contradict the chapters from the standard I gave, you should provide another from the standard that does so.

Comment: @user694733 in my ideone link the line `printf("%d\n", a);` reads an `int` which is written via a `char *`. Is this example http://ideone.com/AlUDzO better?

Comment: @mch Conversion to other pointer type and back is also legal (6.3.2.3p7) However, following code is UB since effective type is not `int`: http://ideone.com/UjOCo9

Answer (score -3):

You should be using `memset`, unless it's very hard to do. Like it doesn't exist in your environment and you can't add an equivalent. It's fast, checks all the right edge cases and is essentially bug-free.

---

That is close enough to working actually.
But `sizeof` produces the size in bytes. You should switch the int to char.

Since all elements involved are of a size which is a multiple of four, you could do something like this, and still get the same result.

```
int* adr = (int*)&obj;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(obj); i+=4) {*adr = 0; adr += 4;}
```

Baring any padding the compiler might insert between the fields, for example. It might put each field on a 8 byte / 64 bits region, so access to it is faster.

Comment: Are you *sure* `obj` can be aliased by an `int *`?

Comment: if `sizeof(obj)` is not a multiple of 4 this won't work at all.

Comment: @MichaelWalz  yup, that's why I qualified the whole answer with "Since all elements involved are of a size which is a multiple of four". Whatever OP is trying to do is bad-practice anyway, but they should at least have more ways to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: Apart from the strict aliasing problem, this also assumes that `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle what do you mean?

Comment: @HoriaComan that may work today, but tomorrow someone adds a char field to the struct and breaks the program. And `sizeof (int)` may be different from 4.

Comment: @MichaelWalz but both today and tomorrow they should be using memset.

Comment: @HoriaComan In general, you can't access a type via a pointer of a different type. That results in undefined behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: @HoriaComan of course `memset` is the way to go here, but you didn't mention this at all in your answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz OP seems aware of memset. I imagine they're asking out of curiosity, or because they're in an environment where it's not available. I'll add an explicit warning to use memset.

Comment: @AndrewHenle but `memset` actually does this.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - `memset` is a library function supplied by the system and is aware of what's possible on the platform. As part of the implementation, it's free to do things conforming C code can not. And a good implementation of `memset` will likely outperform code generated from C as `memset` can be extremely platform-specific, using instructions most compilers don't normally use because they are so platform-specific.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I agree with all that, but the struct aliasing rule does not apply to `char`, [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule/99010#99010) near the end of the accepted answer.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Where does `char` come from?  The answer above aliases the `struct` to an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle OK, misunderstanding. For me the `int` solution was ruled out anyway because if won't work if the size of the struct is not a multiple of 4 (assumimg `sizeof int` is 4).